# Confirming navigation with with custom dialog using setRouteLeaveHook

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-redux

I am trying to use a custom dialog to ask a user for confirmation before navigating away with unsaved data.

Following the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md) I have:

```
  componentDidMount() {
      this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(
        this.props.route,
        this.routerWillLeave
      )
  }
```

But instead of

```
  routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
    if (!this.props.pristine) {
      return 'You have unsaved information, are you sure you want to leave this page?'

    }
```

I have

```
  routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
    if (!this.props.pristine) {
        this.setState({open: true})
        this.forceUpdatate() //necessary or else render won't be called to open dialog
    }
```

The dialog component I am using comes from [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog) which just expects an `open` boolean to control the dialog, it also takes a `handleCancel` and `handleContinue` methods, but I am not sure how to hook it up with `routerWillLeave`.

The `handleCancel` method is simple as it just closes the dialog:

```
  handleCancel() {
    this.setState({open: false})
  };
```

I have wrapped the dialog component in component called `Notification`

```
export default class Notification extends React.Component {

  render() {

   const { open, handleCancel, handleContinue } = this.props

    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={handleCancel}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Continue"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={handleContinue}
      />,
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          actions={actions}
          modal={false}
          open={open}

        >
          You have unsaved data. Discard changes?
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I can call it from the parent component, I have this in the render method:

```
<Notification open={open} handleCancel={this.handleCancel} handleContinue={this.handleContinue}/>
```

Basically my question is how can I wire this up with `routerWillLeave` instead of showing the native browser alert?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `createHistory`, one of the options to it is `getUserConfirmation`, which takes a prompt `message` and a `callback`. For DOM histories (`browserHistory` and `hashHistory`), `getUserConfirmation` calls `window.confirm`, passing it the `message`. The `callback` function receives the return value of `window.confirm` [0].

What you need to do is to provide your own `getUserConfirmation` method that replicates `window.confirm`. When it gets called, you should display your modal and trigger the `callback` depending on which button is clicked.

#### Notification.js

The `<Notification>` component should take the prompt `message` and the `callback` function to call based on the user's action.

```
class Notification extends React.Component {

  contructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      open: false
    }
  }

  handleCancel() {
    this.props.callback(false)
    this.setState({ open: false })
  }

  handleContinue() {
    this.props.callback(true)
    this.setState({ open: false })
  }

  render() {
    const { message } = this.props
    const { open } = this.state
    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleCancel.bind(this)}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Continue"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleContinue.bind(this)}
      />,
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          actions={actions}
          modal={true}
          open={open}
        >
          {message}
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### ModalConfirmation.js

The confirmation modal isn't *really* a part of your UI, which is why I am rendering it in a separate render process than the rest of the app.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Notification from './components/Notification'

export default function = (holderID) => {
  var modalHolder = document.getElementById(holderID)

  return function ModalUserConfirmation(message, callback) {
    ReactDOM.render((
      <Notification open={true} message={message} callback={callback} />
    ), modalHolder)
  }
}
```

This will obviously force you to create your own history object. You cannot just import `browserHistory` or `hashHistory` because those use `window.confirm`. Luckily it is trivial to create your own history. This is essentially the same code as is used in `browserHistory` [1], but it passes `createBrowserHistory` your `getUserConfirmation` function.

#### createConfirmationHistory.js

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
import createRouterHistory from './createRouterHistory'

export default function(getUserConfirmation) {
  return createRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory({
    getUserConfirmation
  })
}
```

#### index.js

Finally, you need to put this all together.

```
import createHistory from './createConfirmationHistory'
import ModalConfirmation from './ModalConfirmation'

const getModalConfirmation = ModalConfirmation('modal-holder')
const history = createHistory(getModalConfirmation)

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={history}>
    // ...
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root')
```

You would have to refactor this a bit if you wanted to use a history singleton, but otherwise it should work. (I haven't actually tested it, though).

[0] https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/v2.x/modules/DOMUtils.js#L38-L40

[1] https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/modules/browserHistory.js

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate response, I've only come around to this problem now and I have a question. I am using react-router-redux to sync the store with history, i.e const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store). How can I append to this history getModalConfirmation?

Comment: You will have to create your own history instead of using `browserHistory`. If you need to use the history instance throughout your project, you could modify the `createConfirmationHistory` that I included above to import your `getUserConfirmation`, create a history instance, and export that instance. That is what the `browserHistory` module does. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/modules/browserHistory.js If that isn't clear I can link an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I haven't tested this and you'll probably have to modify it, but this is the general idea https://gist.github.com/pshrmn/7a7b9a4edddc749d353425919e48707e

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [react-router-navigation-prompt](https://github.com/ZacharyRSmith/react-router-navigation-prompt).

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using `Prompt` from `react-router-dom` with a custom modal from `antd`. Material UI should have very similar functionality.

In my `index.js` I set up my dialog in `getUserConfirmation` of the `Router`:

```
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Modal } from 'antd'
import App from './App'

const { confirm } = Modal

const confirmNavigation = (message, callback) => {
  confirm({
    title: message,
    onOk() {
      callback(true)
    },
    onCancel() {
      callback(false)
    }
  })
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router getUserConfirmation={confirmNavigation}>
    <App />
  </Router>
document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Then you use in it the component you want to prompt if you try to navigation away, using the `when` prop to give a condition to pop up the modal.

```
import { Prompt } from 'react-router-dom'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Prompt
          when={myDataHasNotSavedYet}
          message="This will lose your changes. Are you sure want leave the page?"
        />        
        <RestOfMyComponent/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```